# How to show all sections after cycling visibility?

Tags: markdown-mode

After cycling visibility for some sections, is there a single key combination that will restore visibility to all subsections?

I was trying to isearch for a tab, and, instead of inserting a tab character into the mini-buffer, ended up cycling various sections of a document.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation page](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/), shift-tab should be bound to a function that cycles visibility "globally between the table of contents view (headings only), outline view (top-level headings only), and the full document view."